# YAML : How do I override variables

Tags: yaml

I have a YAML like the following:

```
defaults: &defaults
  username: admin
  password: admin
  agents:
    blueprint: &agent_blueprint
      version: '1'
      auth:
        username: agent
        password: secret
      supported_features:
      - state
      - lifecycle
      - credentials
      - backup
      - restore
  services:
  - &blueprint_service
    id: '24731fb8-7b84-4f57-914f-c3d55d793dd4'
    name: 'blueprint'
    plans:
    - id: 'bc158c9a-7934-401e-94ab-057082a5073f'
      name: 'v1.0-dedicated-xsmall'
      free: false
      manager:
        name: 'director'
        settings:
          prefix: 'blueprint'
          agent: *agent_blueprint
          context:
            agent: *agent_blueprint
```

Now I want to add another node to override the `supported_features` nodes inside the services array. So, I added something like this.

```
development:
  <<: *defaults
  agents:
    blueprint:
      <<: *agent_blueprint
      supported_features:
      - state
      - lifecycle
      - credentials
  services:
  - *blueprint_service
```

However, it does not update the `supported_features` node under `services`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In YAML there are no variables, and I think you have misunderstanding on what the [merge key feature](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) of YAML actually does.

In your second YAML block you do this:

```
development:
  <<: *defaults
```

which has absolutely no effect as you immediately override both of the key-value pairs (with keys `agents` and `blueprints`) and this:

```
agents:
    <<: *agents
```

has no effect because you override the single key `blueprint`.

After that you do:

```
blueprint: &agent_blueprint
  <<: *agent_blueprint
  supported_features:
```

which merges in the keys from the value for `blueprint` that you just started defining, i.e. `supported_features` (the one on the third line) and its value. This is because an alias always takes the definition from the anchor that comes before it (and if there are multiple anchors with the same name, from the latest anchor defined).

So your second example could be written much simpler as:

```
development:
  agents:
    blueprint: 
      supported_features:
      - state
      - lifecycle
      - credentials
  services:
  - *blueprint_service
```

where `*blueprint_service` gets expanded to:

```
id: 24731fb8-7b84-4f57-914f-c3d55d793dd4
name: blueprint
plans:
- free: false
  id: bc158c9a-7934-401e-94ab-057082a5073f
  manager:
    name: director
    settings:
      agent: *agent_blueprint
      context:
        agent: *agent_blueprint
      prefix: blueprint
  name: v1.0-dedicated-xsmall
```

because of the anchors in effect when that anchors is defined in your first YAML block. And `*agent_blueprint` in there to:

```
  auth: {password: secret, username: agent}
  supported_features: [state, lifecycle, credentials, backup, restore]
  version: '1'
```

There is no "updating". An alias gets its value from what the anchor is defined as, when the alias gets parsed.

Comment: I edited my question a little bit so that it is more understandable. I had the merge node from defaults as there were more nodes under it. Which now I have added. As you mentioned, because I have only one node under agents, I have removed the merged node. But the merge node of <<: *agent_blueprint would be required I guess, as it has more nodes which I am not overriding. But still, the supported features are not overridden under services. Could you please have a look?

Comment: As you say there is no updating, what is the right way to define it if I need to update/override those values?

Comment: @Subhankar Use a Python script to update those values using my `ruamel.yaml` library (preferable as it is simple and efficient) or make it into a template and then generate the YAML from there (only do that if your environment already has such templating). The anchor / alias mechanism is there for a different reason than to define variable values (to be used later) and is not flexible enough for what you want.